# undefined method `map' for "1,2":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I need to pass an array in a params, possible? Values can be, for example, `["1","2","3","4","5"]` and these are strings but needs to eb converted to integers later.

I use a react_component in between a rails `form_for`. The html is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="people_id" id="people_id" value={this.state.people} />
```

The people array looks like this:

[image]

How can I pass the array in the `value` of the hidden field? The server error I got was

Im trying to do something like this in a model:

```
ids = params[:people_id]

ids.map do |b|
  Foo.create!(people_id: b.to_i)
end
```

If I `ids.split(",").map` I get symbol to int error.

Edit:

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Still not sure what the issue is as nothing works. Here is a minimal reproduction of my code:

[This answer is my react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react/36326779#36326779) and that's how I add to the array. Still in the component, I have the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="[people_id][]" id="people_id" value={this.state.people} />
```

**_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :data => {:abide => ''}, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <!-- react component goes here -->
 <%= f.submit  "Go", class: "large button" %>
<% end %>
```

The story is, guest can select few people during registration in one go. Those people will be notified when registration is complete. Think of it as "I am inviting these people to bid on my tender". Those numbers, in the array, are `user_id`s.

users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # POST /resource
  def create
   super do |resource|
    ids = params[:people_id].pop # logs now as "people_id"=>["1,2"]
    resource.save!(ids.split(",").map |b| Foo.create!(people_id: b.to_i) end)
   end
  end
end
```

New error on line `resource.save`:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

**Edit #2**

If I only have, in the `create` method:

```
ids.split(",").map do |b|
 resource.save!(Foo.create!(people_id: b.to_i))
end
```

It works! `Foo` is created two times each with the correct `people_id`.

Because I am creating more objects: `Bar`, I do not know how to do that in:

```
 resource.save!(<the loop for Foo> && Bar.create!())
```

The flow must be:

1. Device creates the User
2. Foo is created with the loop
3. Bar is created
4. etc

It has to be done that way as an User object is created on the fly.

Comment: `ids.split(",").map` should work, given that `ids` is a string `"1,2"`

Comment: No. I got `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: Are you sure the people array isn't actually a hash? Have you tried: ids.map { | key, value | Foo.create!(people_id: value.to_i) }

Comment: Still getting `undefined method map for “1,2”:String`

Comment: @jmkoni is right, that sounds more like a hash.  can you post the actual params shown in the log on the request?

Comment: So actually adding on to what @SergioTulentsev said, can you try ids.split(",").map { | b| Foo.create!(people_id: value.to_s.to_i) }

Comment: Ok. The logs looks like this `people_id"=>"1,2"`

Comment: You were correct in your original thinking that you should be able t split and map because its clearly a string.  You said you were trying something in the model, you aren't, by chance, attempting to use params[:people_id] in a model are you?

Comment: Yes i am. I set it to a variable called `ids`. So `ids = params[:people_id]`

Comment: Sorry, not model, a controller.

Comment: " I got no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" - this is impossible, given the code you showed us.

Comment: Ok then, ill show you the entire code by tomorrow

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have added more information.

Comment: Is this _exactly_ the code you're running? It's invalid (block definition is broken).

Comment: "Here is a minimal reproduction" - this is neither minimal (react has nothing to do with this) nor reproduction (I can't run this).

Comment: Even if the block was fine, the code you'd end up with would be `resource.save!([Foo, Foo, Foo])`. This is not something `save!` understands.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes correct. See my updated post.

Comment: Why do you keep cramming things into parameter of save? This is not how it works. Create your foos before the `resource.save`

Comment: It gets complected. `Profile` is one of them so I need the `User.last.id`. User must be created first.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you use parameter keys with brackets on the end to pass arrays.

However you should not concatenate the values as a comma seperated list but rather send each value as a seperate param:

```
GET /foo?people_ids[]=1&people_ids[]=2&people_ids[]=3
```

That way Rails will unpack the parameters into an array:

```
Parameters: {"people_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

The same principle applies to POST except that the params are sent as formdata.

If you want a good example of how this works then look at the rails [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) helper and the inputs it generates.

```
<input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="post_author_ids_1">D. Heinemeier Hansson</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_2" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="post_author_ids_2">D. Thomas</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_3" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<label for="post_author_ids_3">M. Clark</label>
<input name="post[author_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
```

### Updated:

If you intend to implement you own array parameters by splitting a string you should not end the input with brackets:

```
<input type="hidden" name="[people_id][]" value="1,2,3">
```

---

```
{"people_id"=>["1,2,3"]}
```

Notice how people_id is treated as an array and the input value is the first element.

While you could do `params[:people_id].first.split(",")` it makes more sense to use the correct key from the get go:

```
<input type="hidden" name="people_id" value="1,2,3">
```

Also you don't really want to wrap the "root" key in brackets. Thats used in rails to nest a param key in a hash eg. `user[name]`.

Comment: I use react so the state is an array. I add to the array with `concat`. Ill show you that code later.

Comment: You can use a single input and split the string `params[:something].split(",")` but this is the *rails way* of passing arrays.

Comment: I don't have much experience with react but you would need to change the binding so that it generates a input for each item in the array instead of updating the value of single input.

Comment: See my updated post. That is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Ok. Before trying out your updated answer, my loop works. The thing is a user is created with `resource.save` with actions: `resource.save!(Bar.create())`. I'm trying to add a loop in the `resource.save` and that's where the issue is.

Comment: What you are doing is a pretty strange and convoluted way of doing what is usually done with the `ids=` setters (assigning records) or nested attributes. I would recommend you figure out how to do it in vanilla rails before trying to do it with react.