# Shorter way to remove an item by index from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react) post last year and today, I assume things can be simplified.

I need to remove an item from an array but by the index. When by the index, it does not matter if the array has same values. Your typical example:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,2,1] // just an array, not array with objects
let x = 1;

// This will not be an expected result:
// Find all values that is equal to 1 then remove
arr.filter(num => num !== x) //=> [2,3,2]
```

My expectation is when I remove the last element (`1`), for example, the array should be `[1,2,3,2]`:

```
let index = 4; // which is the last "1" in the array
let indexVal = arr.indexOf(4) // 1
let newArray = arr.splice(indexVal, 1) //=> [1,2,3,2]
```

Now, it's 2017, almost '18, is there a shorter way (es5/6) of doing this **without** any polyfil?

Edit:

Think of this as a todo:

```
<ul>
  <li>me</li>
  <li>me</li> // click to delete this one
  <li>you</li>
  <li>me</li>
</ul>
```

To correctly remove that item, I have to delete by the `index` not `value`

Comment: Why are you trying to call `indexOf` on an index?

Comment: you can do this in one line `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(4), 1))`

Comment: @user2357112 Bear with me as im still understanding... that returns something like `-1`

Comment: This code is completely wrong. The errors just happen to produce the final output you were expecting by fluke.

Comment: Try `arr.filter((num, i) => i !== x);` instead.

Comment: ...hey, wait, the answers you received on your previous post already *gave* you the correct code, one line, without `indexOf`.

Comment: Cant be a duplicate. That targets by the value. Look at the answer, it uses `e.target.value`

Comment: @Sylar: `array.splice(index, 1);` is by index. That's why it says `index`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Array.filter` callback gives 2 arguments, number and index and you can filter the array this way.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,2,1] 
let x = 4; //suppose you want to remove element at 4th index

let editedArray = arr.filter((num, index) => index !== x) //editedArray = [1,2,3,2]
```

**EDIT:**

The third parameter gives the whole array. Thanks @Oliver for pointing this out in comment

Comment: I was "playing" with `filter` but could not get it, I forgot to add in the index `(val, index)`. Thanks

Comment: Just for completion: The filter function has also a third parameter where you get the whole array you currently operating on.

Comment: *Shortest* version: `arr.filter((_, i) => i !== x)`

Answer (score 5):

```
arr.splice(index, 1);
```

or if you specifically want to remove the last element:

```
arr.pop();
```

No `indexOf` call. The `indexOf` call never should have been there; it only ever looked like it worked because `indexOf` returns `-1` for an element that isn't present, and `splice` treats negative indices as counting from the end of the array.

Also, `splice` modifies the array in place and returns an array of removed elements, so assigning its return value the way you were doing is misleading.

Comment: You might want to add that both `.splice()` and `.pop()` return the removed element/s so `let newArray = arr.splice(indexVal, 1)` will actually make `newArray = 1`

Comment: So when I `arr.length` what's the amount? I havent tried this as yet.

Comment: @Sylar by the documentation `.splice(indexFromWhichToStartRemoving,numberOfElementsToRemove)` and since it mutates the actual array it returns the elements that were removed. `.pop()` removes the very last element of the array also mutates the array and returns that 1 removed element.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović: It'd be `newArray = [1]`, not `newArray = 1`, but yeah, that's worth mentioning.

Comment: Hi. No pop. It needs to be flexible. Think of it as a todo list with same values and a user deletes either. Only the deleted one should be removed ;)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is the one we use in Redux every day:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
const index = 4 // index of the item you want to remove
const newArr = [...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)]
console.log(newArr) // [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

It might not be the shortest but it is more 2017 and it is **immutable**, which is very important!

Answer (score 1):

Ajay's answer might be what you're looking for. Anyway, there are people like me who prefer slightly-more-lines-but-more-readable/rewritable/maintable solution, I'd do it this way:

```
function removeElementByIndex(arr, x) {
    var newArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(i != x) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
// Usage
removeElementByIndex([1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 4);// outputs: [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

> Now, it's 2017, almost '18, is there a shorter way (es5/6) of doing
>   this **without** any polyfil?

LOL! Many basic things not yet implemented. We'll have to wait for 2118 or another programming language to replace JS (oh wait, there's one, aka jQuery :P ).