# Remove item from array in React

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with removeItem function (it should remove current `<li>` that button is nested in, and item from array on this.state.list), no code currently because I try so much things of that and nothing working so I end up on `console.logs` watch what happened so I deleted it

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Todo.css';

class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [],
            text: ''
        }
        this.textChange = this.textChange.bind(this);
        this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    }

    textChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
        })
    }

    addToList() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            list: prevState.list.concat(this.state.text),
            text: ''
        }))
    }

    removeItem(e) { ?
        ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>My Todo List</h1>
            <h3>Add item</h3>
            <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.textChange(e)}/>
            <button onClick={this.addToList}>+</button>
            <ul>{this.state.list.map((x,y) => {
              return <li key={y}>{x}
              <button onClick={this.removeItem}>-</button>
              </li>})}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Fetch array from state and remove element using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function and set state.

Comment: Possible duplicate [delete-item-from-state-array-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react).

Answer (score 14):

in my solution
eg:

```
const remove = (i) => {
        const arr = data.filter((item) => item.name !== i);
        setData(arr);
    };
```

I filtered the items that are not removed and set again the state

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Comment: i'm sorry that my fault!

Answer (score 8):

Removing item from array **by index**:

```
const newList = this.state.list.splice(index, 1);
```

Removing item from array **by value**:

```
const newList = this.state.list.splice(this.state.list.indexOf(value), 1);
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `splice` here.  But even still `splice` mutates the array directly, which is generally frowned upon in React.

Comment: Yep it is splice not slice! 2 different functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter your list by the issue you want,
and it will be auto removed,
for example, if you want to remove all items = 3 :

list: `prevState.list.filter(x=> x != 3);`

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
removeItem(item) {
    const item = getItem(this.state.list, item.id) // Method to get item in list through comparison (IE: find some item with item.id), it has to return ITEM and INDEX in array
    const newlist = [].concat(list) // Clone array with concat or slice(0)
    newlist.splice(item.index, 1);
    this.setState({list: newlist});       
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pass the index of the item to your `removeItem` function. Like so:

```
removeItem(index) {
  const list = this.state.list;

  list.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({ list });
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>My Todo List</h1>
      <h3>Add item</h3>
      <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.textChange(e)}/>
      <button onClick={this.addToList}>+</button>
      <ul>{
        this.state.list.map((text, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={i}>
              {text}
              <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(i) }>-</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This one remove always 1st item in my Todo List, so if i press to remove last item, it remove 1st. Not working

Comment: I'm sorry but It actually works, missed part from render(), Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the index of the item in the list on click then splice the array:

```
<ul>
  {
    this.state.list.map((x,y) => {
      return (
        <li key={y}>
          {x}
          <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(y)}>-</button>
        </li>
      );
    })
  }
</ul>
```

Then in removeItem:

```
removeItem(index) {
  const list = this.state.list;
  list.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({ list });
}
```

Comment: maybe like this list.splice(index, 1);

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Todo.css';

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      text: ''
    }
    this.textChange = this.textChange.bind(this);
    this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
  }

  textChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    })
  }

  addToList() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      list: prevState.list.concat(this.state.text),
      text: ''
    }))
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    let newList = this.state.list.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({list:newList})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>My Todo List</h1>
        <h3>Add item</h3>
        <input value={this.state.text} onChange={e => this.textChange(e)}/>
        <button onClick={this.addToList}>+</button>
        <ul>{this.state.list.map((x,y) => {
          return <li key={y}>{x}
          <button onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this,y)}>-</button>
          </li>})}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

Comment: This one delete few list items no metter which one you press to delete, so its dont work

Comment: just check once more its actually working as i am passing index of particular  array item @DaveWicomo thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  _deleteTodo(index) {
    console.log("delete " + index);
    this.state.todos.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter(i => i !== index)
    });
  }
```

I had a problem with splice and i honestly don know why. However this method work for me and you can try it! Ps. If anybody know why splice is not working with state and index please let me know i am curious!