# unable to update setState

Tags: reactjs

Tried to update a state. Somehow the setState isn't working..

this is the function and state:

```
state = {
    security: {
      0: { id: "54321", name: "test1"}
      1: { id: "98765", name: "test2"}
              }
}

removeSecInState = (security) => () => {

        var temp = Object.assign({}, this.state.security)
        var temp1 = Object.values(temp)
        var index = temp1.findIndex(id => id.id ===  security.id) //getIndex

        delete temp[0]

        this.setState({security: temp},() =>  {
            console.log(temp, "inside");
            console.log(this.state.security, "inside1")

        })
    }
```

```
console.log(temp, "inside") =  
security: {
      1: { id: "98765", name: "test2"}
              }
```

```
console.log(this.state.security, "inside1") = 
security: {
      0: { id: "54321", name: "test1"}
      1: { id: "98765", name: "test2"}
              }
```

somehow, state is not updated to be the same with temp, always goes back to the previous state

Comment: What you have posted is impossible. If you have deleted `temp[1]` the is no way it will log what you have posted next. Please click on `<>` button and create [mcve]

Comment: ohh sorry about that. :(

Comment: ill try to redo the question, thanks so much mister.

Comment: What you really need is to delete an item from an array in the state. right?

Comment: yes sir. is that possible?

Comment: One thing I have noticed. Since your next state depends on the previous state the recommended way is to use callback version of `setState(oldState => patch)` to avoid state overrides.

Comment: Yeah. That is possible. Let me send you a link. Follow up the below answer too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react

Comment: Here is the link. I have done the same thing using that document.https://vegibit.com/how-to-delete-an-item-from-an-array-in-react/

Comment: thank you so much for the resources mister, really appreciate it :bow

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have not included the `this` keyword before state, also you should

Try this

```
this.state = {
    security: {
      0: { id: "54321", name: "test1"}
      1: { id: "98765", name: "test2"}
              }
}
```

Also you should try to refactor the code a little bit

Maybe like this

```
this.state = {
    security: [
      { id: "54321", name: "test1"},
      { id: "98765", name: "test2"}
              ]
}

removeSecInState(sec) {
    this.setState({
        security: this.state.security.filter(item => item.id !== sec.id)
    })
}
```

Comment: OP uses class property. Also if you were right won't it cause a completely different issue then? :)

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, will update if it works. :bow:

Comment: Well it depends on where you have declared the state, if it's declared inside its constructor it should be with the this keyword

Comment: But from the code it is almost obvious that state has been declared within class body as a property. Same for the `removeSecInState`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is right, it doesn't seem to make any difference. Still, the error is in the implementation of ```removeSecInState```. i suggest changing the security to an array of objects instead of an object with nested objects first, and then changing the ```removeSecInState``` as it's written in the answer

Comment: okay mister, will try to do that. thanks again you guys :bow: