# Unexpected token, expected ";" at render ()

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error at line 145 as stated in the heading in my code but i can't really trace the error to it's source as it is pointing at a section that looks normal to me. Below is the error and my code:

[Unexpected token, expected ";"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgu7m.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Popup from '../../../Widget/Popup';
import api from '../../../Api';
// import TokenContext from '../../../token-context';
import UserBar from '../../UserBar';

export default class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      /* in case we are editing an existed question
         we will update these stats in `componentdidmount`
         otherwise, we are creating a new question
      */
      questionName: '',
      questionType: '',
      timeLimit: 0,
      points: 0,
      video: '',
      photo: '',
      // flag the toggles to show input bar where user attach youtube url
      showInput: false,
      // Answers to this question
      answers: [],
      // there could be more than 1 correct answers to this question
      // in multi type question
      correctAnswers: [],
      // keep track of the answer user want to add
      newAnswerInput: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const { token } = this.state;
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log(token);
    const quizId = match.params[0];
    const questionIndex = match.params[1];
    const path = `admin/quiz/${quizId}`;
    const response = await api(path, 'GET', null, token);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const r = await response.json();
      if (questionIndex <= r.questions.length) {
        this.setState({ ...r.questions[questionIndex] });
      }
    } else {
      const r = await response.json();
      const popup = <Popup message={JSON.stringify(r.error)} />;
      ReactDOM.render(popup, document.getElementById('popup'));
    }
  }

  changeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  // separate handler to store file into the state
  // since we retrieve the file using target.files[0]
  uploadFile = (event) => {
    this.setState({ photo: event.target.files[0] });
  }

  toggleInput = (state) => {
    this.setState({ showInput: !state.showInput });
  }

  renderThumbnail = () => {
    const { video, photo } = this.state;
    if (video !== '') {
      return (
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src={video} />
          <track src="" kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="english_captions" />
        </video>
      );
    return (<img src={photo} alt="photo" width="320" height="auto" />);
  }

  timeLimitOptions = () => {
    times = [5, 10, 20, 30, 60, 90, 120, 240];
    timesOptions = times.map((t) => (
     <option value={t.toString()}>{t}</option>
    ));
    return timesOptions;
  }

  addAnswer = () => {
    const { newAnswerInput, answers } = this.state;
    if (newAnswerInput !== '') {
      this.setState({ 
        answers: [...answers, newAnswerInput],
        newAnswerInput: '', 
      });
    }
  }

  // handler that modify the list of correct answers in state
  changeCorrectAnswer = (event) => {
    const { correctAnswers } = this.state;
    var newCorrectAnswers = [...correctAnswers];
    // following code is adapted from
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react
    if (newCorrectAnswers.includes(event.target.name)) {
      var index = array.indexOf(event.target.name);
      newCorrectAnswers.splice(index, 1); 
    } else {
      newCorrectAnswers.push(event.target.name);
    }
    this.setState({correctAnswers: newCorrectAnswers});
  }

  updateQuestion = async () => {
    const { token } = this.state;
    const { match, history } = this.props;
    console.log(token);
    const quizId = match.params[0];
    const questionIndex = match.params[1];
    const path = `admin/quiz/${quizId}`;
    var response = await api(path, 'GET', null, token);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      // do an update api request with the new question info
      const r = await response.json();
      const newQuestion = {...this.state};
      r.questions = [...r.questions, newQuestion];
      response = await api(path, 'PUT', r, token);
      // if we update with the new question successfully, navigates to previous page
      if (response.status === 200) {
        history.goBack();
      } else {
        const r = await response.json();
        const popup = <Popup message={JSON.stringify(r.error)} />;
        ReactDOM.render(popup, document.getElementById('popup'));
      }
    } else {
      const r = await response.json();
      const popup = <Popup message={JSON.stringify(r.error)} />;
      ReactDOM.render(popup, document.getElementById('popup'));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { answers, correctAnswers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="flex-container-column">
        <UserBar />
        <form onsubmit={this.updateQuestion}>
            <input 
            type="text" 
            name="questionName" 
            onChange={this.changeHandler} 
            value="Click to start typing your question"
            required />
          {this.renderThumbnail}
          <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleInput}>
            upload a video
          </button>
          {showInput
          && (
            <div className="flex-container-column">
              <input type="text" name="videoUrl" onChange={this.changeHandler} required />
              <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleInput}>
                Attach
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
          <label>
            Upload your file
          </label>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.uploadFile} />
          <label for="questionType">
            Question type
          </label>
          <select name="questionType">
            <option value="single">
              single
              <br />
              Player can only select one of the answer
            </option>
            <option value="multi">
              multi
              <br />
              Player can select multiple answer before submitting
             </option>
          </select>
            <label for="timeLimit">
            Time limit
            </label>
            <select name="timeLimit" onChange={this.changeHandler}>
            {this.timeLimitOptions}
            </select>
            <label for="points">
            Points
            </label>
            <select name="points">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1000" selected>1000</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Question" />
          // following code is a snippet adapted from 
          // https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/implementing-radio-list-with-text-input-in-reactjs
          <div>
            {answers.map((answer) => (
              <div>
                <input 
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={answer}
                  value={answer}
                  onChange={this.changeCorrectAnswer}
                />
                <label for={answer}>
                  {answer}
                </label>
              </div>
            ))}
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="newAnswerInput"
              checked={correctAnswers.includes(answer)}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ newAnswerInput: e.target.value })} 
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addAnswer}>
              Add answer
            </button>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Can someone point me out where should I start looking at first when I see this kind of error?
Thanks!

Comment: When dealing with a syntax error such as this, remove members/expressions before the error and see if removing any of them fixes the issue. Chances are, it's the part you removed that contains the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check all your functions and declarations for proper opening and closing of brackets.

You missed a **}** in your **renderThumbnail** function

Your current function

```js
renderThumbnail = () => {
    const { video, photo } = this.state;
    if (video !== '') {
      return (
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src={video} />
          <track src="" kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="english_captions" />
        </video>
      );
    return (<img src={photo} alt="photo" width="320" height="auto" />);
  }
```

How it should be

```js
renderThumbnail = () => {
    const { video, photo } = this.state;
    if (video !== '') {
      return (
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
          <source src={video} />
          <track src="" kind="captions" srcLang="en" label="english_captions" />
        </video>
      );
    }
    return (<img src={photo} alt="photo" width="320" height="auto" />);
  }
```

Comment: Ah, my bad, that fixed it. Thanks!