# Javascript splice working wrong with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My splice is deleting everything but item clicked.
I have studied a popular post here about that, but it didn't worked for me, same for that one about redux and modifying a state.
I have a redux function which is meant to delete an item - action.item contains an unique index of an item that I want to be deleted:

```
const deleteItem = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        orderedItems: state.orderedItems.splice(action.item, 1)
    });
};
```

updateObject looks like that:

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    };
};
```

Different solutions as f.e:

```
const deleteItem = (state, action) => {
    return state.orderedItems.filter(element => element !== action.item);
};
```

Not only don't work, but also gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined because im using mapping to show every item

```
let basket = (
            <aside>
                {this.props.orderedItems.map((orderItem, i) => (
                    <OrderElement key={i} id={i} title={orderItem.item} />
                ))}
            </aside>
        );
```

Thats an initial state of the store:

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    numberOfReservations: "",
    orderedItems: [],
};
```

Before clicking Reco3:
[Page before clicking an item to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mtAh.png)
And after clicking:
[Page after clicking and Reco3 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh1ps.png)
Im completly clueless, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Instead of adding links to images of the rendered markup add a [mcve] with examples for `state.orderedItems` and `action.item`

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) removes elements from the array in place and returns the elements removed.

Comment: @hereticmonkey I understand, but still don't know how to approach the problem, as every other solution makes my page go down. I added a bit more info to the post

Comment: In React, and especially Redux, you want to make sure you don't manipulate state arrays directly, because React won't be able determine it's changed. You need to set the array to a new array, in this case without the item you want to remove. There are a few questions about this already on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete item from state array in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/delete-item-from-state-array-in-react)

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible code in codesandbox ? Looks like everything fine

Comment: @hereticmonkey after 2hrs of searching, i finally did it like that  
`let test = [...state.orderedItems];  
test.splice(action.item, 1);  
return {
        ...state, orderedItems: test
    };`  
Thing i was missing all the time was spreading the original state so it wont update, or if it did, my page wont react to that change. Anyway, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but isn't this because splice returns the removed items from the array?

You're setting orderedItems to the item that you removed.

```
let months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
let output = months.splice(0, 1);
//Output: ["Jan"]
//Months: ['March', 'April', 'June']
```

So, you might want to use something other than splice, that or implement it in a different way.

Comment: I edited a post and added clarification - I tried other solutions, but they arent working at all giving me errors or just doing nothing, and the problem is I have no clue what am I doing wrong.