# localStorage.removeItem() is only working if i delete in the order that it was last added. why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, local-storage

heres a video of what it is doing: https://youtu.be/NpMVGScqWLI

you see near 25 seconds it works only if i remove from last item added.

for example if i add in this order:

1. scary movie 1
2. scary movie 2
3. scary movie 3
4. scary movie 4

is only deleting if i click the remove in this order: 4,3,2,1.

if i click in this order 1, 4, 5, 6 it just mixes up the items order in local storage and does not delete...

```js
// get items from local storage and render on page**

useEffect(() => {
  let arrayOfValues = Object.values(localStorage);
  console.log("localstoragearray:", arrayOfValues);
  if (arrayOfValues.length > 0) {
    arrayOfValues.forEach((movie) => {
      let storedMovies = JSON.parse(movie);
      nominated.push(storedMovies);
      setNominated(nominated);
      setNominatedCount(nominatedCount + nominated.length);
    });
  }
}, []);


// remove nominated movies and from local storage**

const removeNomination = (movie) => {
  localStorage.removeItem(movie.imdbID);
  nominated.splice(
    nominated.findIndex((movie) => movie.title),
    1
  );
  setNominated(nominated);
  setNominatedCount(nominatedCount - 1);
};
add movies to local storage //add movies to local storage
useEffect(() => {
  nominated.forEach((movie) => {
    if (nominated.length > 5) {
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem(movie.imdbID, JSON.stringify(movie));
  });
  console.log("nominated:", nominated);
}, [nominated]);
```

```html
<Button key={index} onClick={()=> { removeNomination(movie); }}>
         Remove
    </Button>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] like codesandbox

Comment: `let arrayOfValues = Object.values(localStorage)` what is this line expected to do?

Comment: It appears as though the code has been posted twice, since `removeNomination` is declared as a `const` twice, which would throw a Syntax error.

Comment: sorry i made an error tryign to post the code. i updated it. 

let arrayofvalues grabs the values from local storage

Comment: You're mutating the `nominated` array in-place. You should treat it as immutable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326808/3321016

Comment: that stops my component from rendering unfortunately.