# Remove an item from a nested array with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to remove an item from my state using React Hooks. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My data looks as follows and I'm trying to remove individual item within the 'items' array.

```
const MYDATA = {
    id: '0001',
    title: 'A good title',
    items: [
      {
        itemid: 0,
        title: 'Cheddar',
        variants: [
          { id: '062518', grams: 200, price: 3.00},
          { id: '071928', grams: 400, price: 5.50},
        ]
      },
      {
        itemid: 1,
        title: 'Edam',
        variants: [
          { id: '183038', grams: 220, price: 2.50},
          { id: '194846', grams: 460, price: 4.99},
        ]
      },
      {
        itemid: 2,
        title: 'Red Leicester',
        variants: [
          { id: '293834', grams: 420, price: 4.25},
          { id: '293837', grams: 660, price: 5.99},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

When i click on my 'Remove' button map breaks, and I think this is because my my state is malformed, but I'm not sure.

An example of the problem I face can be seen here -
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-joliot-4wp1q?file=/src/App.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question description itself. Code sandbox is fine but shouldn't be needed to answer the question.

Comment: To remove an item from an array within the state, see: [How to delete an item from state array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36326612/1218980)

Comment: And to update a nested state property: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040721/1218980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` is embedded inside.

```
  const removeMyCheese = (cheeseId) => {
    console.log(cheeseId)

    setMyCheeses(prev => {
      const items = prev.items.filter(item => item.itemid !== cheeseId)
      return {
        ...prev,
        items
      }
    })

  }
```

Feel free to amend it whatever your logic is, i for now only delete that item.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you believe it solved your problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are executing `map` on an object and not an array. Hence you get the undefined error. Perhaps you intended to run the map function on `myCheeses.items`?

Answer (score -2):

This problem is due to the fact that you should apply `.map` on an array (here in your `item`). You can use either:

```
const removeMyCheese = (cheeseId) => {
    console.log(cheeseId);
    setMyCheeses((prevState) => {
      let items = prev.items.filter(item=>item.itemid!==cheeseId);
      return {
        ...prevState,
        items
      };
    });
  };
```

or (it is not a good solution though => `splice` **mutates the state in place, which is bad practice in React**.)

```
const removeMyCheese = (cheeseId) => {
    console.log(cheeseId);
    setMyCheeses((prevState) => {
      let items = prev.items.splice(cheeseId);
      return {
        ...prevState,
        items
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the state in place, which is bad practice in React.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I did not know that, I modified the answer based on filtering and added your comment as well. thank you.

Comment: It's better, but I can't recommend enough _not_ to use `splice` at all in this use-case.