# React Hook state updating without calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am running into an issue with React where my hook state is updating without my calling setState.

```
  const [dataSet2, setDataSet2] = React.useState([
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 9],
  ]);

  const badFunction = () => {
    let selections = [];
    let newSelections = [];
    let winPercent = 0;
    let newWinPercent = 1;
    const depth = 2;
    const dataHolderTest = dataSet2;
    let firstWeekTest = dataHolderTest[0];
    const weekOneTeamsTest = firstWeekTest.slice(0, depth);

    for (const weekOneTeamTest of weekOneTeamsTest) {
      let secondWeekTest = dataHolderTest[1];

      newWinPercent = weekOneTeamTest.win_percent * newWinPercent;
      newSelections.push(weekOneTeamTest.team);
      for (const team2 of secondWeekTest) {
        removeAllSelectedTeams(newSelections, secondWeekTest, team2);
      }
    }

    console.log(dataSet2);

};

  const removeAllSelectedTeams = (selections, dataHolder, team) => {
    if (selections.includes(team.team)) {
      const currentTeam = dataHolder.indexOf(team);
      dataHolder.splice(currentTeam, 1);
    }
    return dataHolder;
  };
```

I've been picking through this for a while now and it seems like the `removeAllSelectedTeams` function is the problem.

Still I don't understand how my `dataSet2` is being altered without calling the hook `setDataSet2`

Comment: [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the current state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an item from state array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/how-to-delete-an-item-from-state-array)

Comment: @EmileBergeron but I am not running `.splice` on dataSet2 only on a copy of it.

Comment: Assigning it to another identifier doesn't make a copy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: You're not using a copy. This `const dataHolderTest = dataSet2` doesn't create a copy. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1218980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of an array or an object, you need to do it like this.
 `listTwo = [...listOne]` or  `ObjectTwo = {...ObjectOne}`. Simply using `=` and not using the spread operator does not make a copy of that array or object for you, rather gives you another reference to the same array or object.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the array to `dataHolderTest` instead of assigning it equal to `dataSet2` with the spread operator `...`

This way your not changing the original `dataSet2` variable when interacting with `dataHolderTest`

`const dataHolderTest = [...dataSet2]`