# Are "How to delete an item from state array?" answers wrong cuz setState is async?

Tags: reactjs

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/how-to-delete-an-item-from-state-array), all the answers use this form of `setState`:

```
this.setState( { items: this.state.items.filter() } )
```

Which means this is a case of "*new state is derived from the current state*".

However, in this [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) about async behavior of `setState`, in this case, this callback form MUST be used instead:

```js
this.setState( currState => ( { items: currState.items.filter() } ) )
```

My question is, are those answer all wrong, and if so, what are the consequences? Or is it somehow still acceptable?

Comment: I mean `this.state.items` will always be the same value in a particular render pass... I personally don't really see when the async nature would be an issue... do you have an example?

Comment: I recommend you change the title, to be specifically about the async nature that was mentioned in the docs. You can still reference the issue linked in the question as an example.

Comment: bad practice vs good practice
In some cases, the first option could lead to unwanted behavior

Comment: @Elias An example is exactly what I'm asking for :)

Comment: The linked question's proposed solution is using `array#filter` instead of `array#splice` which mutates the array. Using `array#filter` is in recommendation with react, since it returns new array and doesn't modify the existing array. IMO, both your approaches will work, since you are not mutating your array.

Comment: @HassanImam No it's not about mutating arrays. It's about having an up-to-date version of array to calculate the next state.

Comment: @HassanImam the question is about `this.setState( { items: this.state.items.filter() } )` vs `this.setState( currState => ( { items: currState.items.filter() } ) )`

Answer (score 1):

The issue only occurs if your code design is (what I think) "bad". Normally, you expect to update the value that is used in the current render. So for example, if the currently displayed `num` is 5, and you want to increase it, you would want the number to be 6. But if you now set the `num` to 10 before doing `setNum(num + 1)`, the output won't be 11, but 6, because it used the currently rendered value (5) + 1 (Which is what I would expect). If you wanted it to use "the current state", so the 10 from the previous `setNum`, you would need to use the callback version.

That was sort of complicated, so here an example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default ({ name }) => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(5);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <button onClick={changed}>Change!</button>
      <button onClick={changedWithCallback}>Change with callback!</button>
      <button onClick={resetted}>Reset!</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  function changed() {
    setNum(10);
    setNum(num + 1);
  }

  function changedWithCallback() {
    setNum(10);
    setNum((state) => state + 1);
  }

  function resetted() {
    setNum(5);
  }
};
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x5vpst?file=Hello.tsx)

Comment: If this is hard to understand (I'm not sure if I managed to explain it well), please leave a comment :)