# How to remove one item from an array if matched?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have something like this

`mainArray ["a","a","b","c","d"]`

And once user click one of these letters I'm pushing it to a new array and hidden that selected item from main array, but the problem here is that if I select "a" letter from array both "a" will be hidden, how can I fix that?

**this is what I've tried**

```
style={[newArray.find((item) => item === mainArray[i])
        ? styles.hideItem
        : styles.showItem]}
```

**Once `newArray` Received it will be hidden from `mainArray`**

Comment: You should find by the index of the letter that was clicked, not the letter itself.

Comment: Can you provide more information pls , if so I can approve as a correct answer?

Comment: I don't know how your code works, so I cannot provide a concrete example. You would have to edit your question with the code that shows what `mainArray` and `newArray` is, and also what `i` is.

Comment: Sorry that was happened by mistake, check above code now, Array was mainArray

Comment: I get a tiny little bit worried about mutating arrays when I see the word _React_ in the question.  Just in case it is the intent of any passers-by to attempt to do this, here's my gentle but paranoid reminder to be careful not to mutate React state.  See also, [the React way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326612/how-to-delete-an-item-from-state-array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` to get the position of the first match. Then you can use `splice()` to remove it.

```
let index = mainArray.indexOf(letter);
if (index != -1) { // if found
    newArray.push(mainArray[index]); // push to new array
    mainArray.splice(index, 1); // and remove from main array
}
```