# React: Run code in setState and avoid side effect by strictmode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple react component, the purpose is to create a list in which each item will be toggle in or out on click.

```
export type Choice= {
  id: string
  value: string
}



function Component({choices}){
    const [selectedChoices, setSelectedChoices] = useState<Choice[]>([])
  const handleSelectChoice = useCallback((choice: Choice) => {
    setSelectedChoices((p) => {
      const idx = p.findIndex((c) => c.id === choice.id)
      if (idx > -1) {
        p.splice(idx, 1)
        console.log(p)

        return [...p]
      } else {
        console.log(p, "SD")
        return p.concat(choice)
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
            {choices.map((choice) => (
              <button
                key={choice.id}
                type="button"
                className={` ${
                  selectedChoices.find((c) => c.id === choice.id) ? "selected" : ""
                }`}
                onClick={() => handleSelectChoice(choice)}
              >
                {choice.value}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
  )
}
```

After some debugging (using refs and console logs), I found out that react development mode is triggering the set function twice. [image]
Whenever the user clicks the button in strict mode, the state won't change at all because the `setSelectedChoices` gets called twice, basically canceling the user's action.

I understand the importance of strict mode and could not make it work yet. I can try and make it work using refs but wanted to know if there is any other way. How can I run such useState setters in strict mode and avoid side-effects? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `p.splice()` is modifying your state, I would use a different method (such as `.filter()`) to create a new array that excludes the index, a few approaches: [How to delete an item from state array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36326612)

Comment: Thank you @NickParsons! This did solve my problem. I am not sure why it wasn't working earlier, I was providing a new array using the spread operator

Comment: I'm guessing when strict mode double invokes your state setter function it doesn't take into account what you returned from it, it just passes through the same reference (`p`) for both calls, and since you were modifying it directly you were getting the removed version on the second invocation.

Comment: I think it is worth mentionning that trying to circumvent strictmode's remount is very bad pratice. React does this on purpose, it is not a bug, it is intended to be like that in development mode. React will: mount, unmount then re-mount your component, triggering all the logic and effects as a production environment would along the way. That is meant to help you find issues like the one pointed out by @NickParsons. Component remounting will happen naturally in production aswell and should be thought about in your code. If it doesnt work in dev mode, there is a very real chance it wont in prod

Comment: I guess you could create a cooldown for the button. Would that work?

Comment: You could also use debounce.

Comment: But debounce would cost a little bit of performance.